# to match images in R based on their pixels value

Tags: r, image-processing

function()
    {

```
img1<-readImage("image.jpg") 


img2<-img1+0.2

img1.b<-sum(img1[,,1:3])
img1.max<-length(img1[,,1:3])

diff1<-img1.b/img1.max

toincr<-increment(diff1)
img4<-img1
img4[,,1:3]<-img1[,,1:3]+toincr


img2.b<-sum(img2[,,1:3])

img2.max<-length(img2[,,1:3])
diff2<-img2.b/img2.max
toincr<-increment(diff2)
img3<-img2
img3[,,1:3]<-img2[,,1:3]+toincr


if(length(img3)==length(img4))
{
    paste(100*sum(img3==img4)/length(img3),"%")
}

}

function(diff)
{
brightness<-0.25
incr<-brightness-diff
return(incr)
}
```

i have written above test function which read an image then create a copy and brighten that copy image.then i am adjusting the brightness of both the image to make them equally brighten with value 0.25 i.e. image img3 and img4.when i an comparing these two images using  then its showing result as 0% but expected result is 100%.how should i modify the program??

Comment: The problem is that you are changing the value of each pixel when your brighten it. therefore 0% of the pixels which match [expect for white/max R,G,B] pixels which should be the same. What are you trying to determine with the comparison function?

Comment: actually i want to compare the images taken from a camera installed at a site.The camera takes the images whenever there is movement at the site since site has movement sensors installed.i am comparing the images with the previously taken images of the site to determine what % of pixels have been changed in the image.I am first adjusting the images brightness since images might have been taken at different brightness level..

Comment: I think the problem here is that unless your light (and camera conditions) are EXACTLY identical, your pixels are different, since they have no intrinsic concept of shapes, movement or anything like that. Probably the best thing for you to do is to reduce the resolution of your image and increase the contrast (say give each pixel only 4 possible brightnesses) so you are looking for major changes in the blocks. But if you're trying to make your own accurate motion / change sensing analytic it could get VERY complicated quite quickly. Can you give more info on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to create a function which compares the images to a previously taken and stored images to determine whether a person has enterd into the room or not.The stored images were taken when there was no one in the room.When anyone enters into the room then camera takes the image since movement sensors are installed into the room.The new image is then compared to previously taken image to determine the % change in the pixels.

Comment: I've updated my answer to give an example of one approach

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here with `png` library

```
require(png)
img1<-readPNG("apple1.png")
img2<-readPNG("apple2.png")

if(length(img1)==length(img2)){   # check same pixel number
  paste(100*sum(img1==img2)/length(img1),"%")
}

#[1] "32.098125 %"
```

It compare the 2 arrays to give you a BOOLEAN array of matches. The sum() of this gives you the number of matching pixels.Divide by total pixels (length() of array) to give you the matching factor (* 100 for percent)

**OK, so answer edited following the comments!**

Firstly, a caveat. The fields of image comparison and change detection are extremely complicated and a lot of commercial work has gone into them, you may be better off using a commercial package rather than re-inventing the wheel.

There is a good paper on intruder detection algorithms here:http://ijcnis.org/index.php/ijcnis/article/viewFile/88/87

However, the question is about R and it deals with useful concepts, so here is *an* (admittedly simplistic) answer:

When you are looking a sequential frames, you need to remember that at normal resolutions, tiny changes in light and exposure settings will make your images completely different for the purposes of basic arithmetical computation. You also need to be aware that a tiny movement in camera due to vibration or whatever (e.g. ~ 1/10000 of a degree for a 15 degree angle of view camera at 400x400) can misalign your pixels so that they CANNOT be compared even with brightness adjusting algorithms)

So to make this work, you need to do 2 things:
1) de-resolve the image (i.e. aggregate the pixels up to less blocks)
2) bucket the brightness score so that small changes in values as per normal shift do not give you false signals.

Try this:

For example, with 2 sample images:

Empty Room

[image]

Intruder

[image]

```
require(png)

img.reference<-readPNG("room-empty.png")     # empty room as reference
img.empty<-readPNG("room-empty.png")         # empty room copy
img.person<-readPNG("room-with-person.png")  # room with person in it

# function to de-resolve image into levels (n=granularity)
# and divide the image up into blocks (n=result.length)
chunkImage<-function(image,granularity=10,result.length=100){

  img.1D<-(image[,,1]+image[,,2]+image[,,1])/3
  pix.n<-length(img.1D)
  groups<-rep(1:result.length,each=ceiling(pix.n/result.length))[1:pix.n]
  imgmap.new<-aggregate(as.vector(img.1D),list(newpix=groups),mean)
  return(as.numeric(cut(imgmap.new$x,c(0:granularity)/granularity)))

}

# this returns an array (of reduced granularity) which describes each image in simpler terms
# you can think of it as a de-resolution or grouping function

chunkImage(img.reference)
#[1] 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 6 6 7 7 7 7 6 5 5 5 6 6 5 5 5 5
#[52] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 5 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 4

# so to compare an empty room against reference
sum(chunkImage(img.empty)!=chunkImage(img.reference))
#[1] 0
# Score 0 so probably nothing to worry about

# now to compare with the image containing the person
sum(chunkImage(img.person)!=chunkImage(img.reference))
#[1] 14
# score 14 may indicate a person
```

You will have to tinker with the resolution & granularity depending on the specifics of your site & environment.

PS: here are visual representations of the de-resolved images, to show you how they can visually be seen as different;

```
m.p<-matrix(chunkImage(img.person),ncol=10)/10
m.e<-matrix(chunkImage(img.empty),ncol=10)/10

m.p.big<-matrix(sapply(apply(m.p,1,function(x)rep(x,40)),function(x)rep(x,40)),ncol=400,byrow=T)
m.e.big<-matrix(sapply(apply(m.e,1,function(x)rep(x,40)),function(x)rep(x,40)),ncol=400,byrow=T)
m.alpha<-matrix(rep(1,160000),ncol=400)

length(m.e.big)

writePNG(array(c(rep(m.p.big,3),m.alpha),dim=c(400,400,4)),"person-deresolved.png")
writePNG(array(c(rep(m.e.big,3),m.alpha),dim=c(400,400,4)),"empty-deresolved.png")
```

[image]
[image]